# Ember - Update model on save not as user types

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-app-kit

I am creating an app using Ember App Kit with Ember Data. I have an items resource that has both a create and edit form. For various design reasons I do not want to have the model updated or created till the user hits a save button. I am not sure the best deign pattern for doing this in Ember since the default is to bind the form fields to the model which updates it as data is input.

Comment: After the fact I have discovered another solution if using Ember Data. I learnt that there is a `rollback` method on the models that allow you to rollback unsaved model data. Using the `isDirty` property on the model you can check on `willTransition` to see if the model has changes, confirm with the user they want to discard those changes, and if so roll them back using the built in method. Very clean and drops the required code by a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a temporary property on your controller.

```
App.FooController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    userName: '',

    createData: function() {
        this.get('store').createRecord({
            name: this.get('userName')
        }).save();

        this.set('userName', '');
    },

    saveData: function() {
        this.set('model.name', this.get('userName'));
        this.set('userName', '');
    }
});
```

Bind to the `userName` property for the text field (or whatever), then transfer the value over when the user clicks the save button.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Since the edit and create controllers will have the same fields and the form is using a partial would you recommend creating a mixin with the properties that are to be set on the controllers? Thanks for the solution, simple but will work well.

Comment: I generally only edit data in one place, so I've never created a mixin for that. However, if I were going to edit the same type of object in multiple places, I would certainly try to factor that into some kind of reusable functionality. If the template is always the same, I would go with a view or component. If the template changes, a mixin would work well.

Comment: Do you know of the best design pattern in Ember for implementing an edit and create for a resource since they are basically the same functionality with just slightly different results? Perhaps there is already some literature out there that you could point me to (I tried a quick search before divining into this). Thanks for taking the time to respond to this it's been really helpful.

Comment: I don't know of any particular pattern, but there is a way to make it easier. The `createRecord` function takes a hash of properties and values which you can pass to `setProperties` on an existing model. You could use that hash as common functionality, and have your functions differ by whether they call `createRecord` or `saveProperties`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can create an `Ember.Object` to which you copy the model properties and then bind the form to that object. Then copy the properties back to the model upon save. You can probably save some code this way.

Comment: Right, so same principal but using an Ember object instead of having them as properties directly on the controller.

Comment: Yes, and then you have a reusable function to create the object from model properties.